# PHP: wrong result while using comma

Tags: php, number-formatting

when i input numbers with comma i get error! and the result i get is not correct. 
 i get this Error :Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aufgaben\plus1.php on line 34

HTML Code:

```
<form action ="Tankfüllung.php" method="post"><p>liter1:<input 
type="text"name="num1"size="20"/><p>liter2:<input type="text" name="num2" 
size="20"/><input type="submit" value="Summer" name="submit"/></form>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php 
function checkPost($x) {
$result = true;
if (!array_key_exists($x,$_POST)) { return false; }
$result &= (isset($x) && $x != ''); 
return $result;
}
if( isset($_POST["num1"]) || isset($_POST["num2"])) { 
$liter1 = $_POST['num1']; 
$liter2 = $_POST['num2'];
$geld = 1.499;
$liter = ($liter1+$liter2);
$preis = ($liter*$geld);  
echo "Die Benzinkosten betragen für $liter Liter $preis €";
} else {
echo "Fehlermeldung: mindestens 1 Feld wurde nicht korrekt übermittelt.";
}
?>
```

Comment: what ecactly the code in line 34?

Comment: _“when i input numbers with comma i get error!”_ - of course you do, because that is not a “format” PHP recognizes. The decimal point is `.`, and nothing else. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php If you want to “localize” this to use a different decimal point character, then you have to replace it with a dot before you parse it as a number.

Comment: @shushu304: This line  $liter = ($liter1+$liter2);

Comment: What was your input!? What is your desire output? Your question is not clear! Please edit it

Comment: @KaushikC: My input  40,5 and 35,7

Comment: If you are using commas in input, then you have to separate those numbers using explode function in PHP. then do your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line: `$liter = ($liter1+$liter2);` 
is trying to add two numeric or float values

if you're provide `$liter1` or `$liter2` with comma like "1,234" this will not work, because it's invalid numeric format in PHP

you can simply do this by replacing comma `,` to dot `.`

```
$liter1 = "1,234";
$liter1 = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $liter1));

echo $liter1;
// will print 1.234
```

or even better through

[*NumberFormatter* class](http://php.net/class.numberformatter) with its [`parse` method](http://php.net/numberformatter.parse).